# Statistics of Win Streaks in 50/50 Scenario

Tags: probability, statistics

So assuming every attempt is a 50/50 with either a win or a loss, after 10,000 attempts statistically how many streaks of 1 win, 2 wins, 3 wins, etc. should there be? Like something like this Win Streaks- 1-_ 2-_ 3_ etc and is there like a pattern to it or even any way to know?

Comment: Does a 2-win streak count also as two 1-win streaks, or does a 1-win streak have to be sandwiched between two losses?

Comment: @Adam a 1 winstreak can either be the first attempt being a win followed by a loss or a win sandwiched between 2 losses, so a 2-winstreak only counts as a 2 winstreak and a 5 winstreak only counts as a 5 winstreak etc

Comment: There will not be a pattern, but there will be a distribution.  Very approximately with $n$ attempts you might expect about $\frac{n}{8}$ winning streaks of length $1$, about $\frac{n}{16}$ winning streaks of length $2$, about $\frac{n}{32}$ winning streaks of length $3$, and so on though with more relative uncertainty for the longer winning streaks, and the longest winning streak may be of the order of $\log_2(n)$ (so not far from $16$ if $n=10^5$ as in your example.  You could say the same for losing streaks

Answer (score 1):

It's at least possible to calculate the expected value of all these quantities.  Let's say there are $N$ attempts and let $X_1, \dots, X_N$ be the individual attempts (where $X_i = 1$ means a win on attempt $\#i$ and $X_i = 0$ means a loss on attempt $\#i$).  Let $Q_1$ be the number of $1$-win streaks, $Q_2$ the number of $2$-win streaks, etc.

We can write $Q_1$ as a sum of indicators:
$$
Q_1 = 1_{X_1=1, X_2=0} + \sum_{i=1}^{N-2} 1_{X_i=0, X_{i+1}=1, X_{i+2}=0} + 1_{X_{N-1}=0, X_N = 1}.
$$

Then it's easy to calculate the expected value
$$
\mathbb{E}[Q_1] = \frac14 + (N-2)\frac18 + \frac14 \approx \frac{N}{8}.
$$

We can do a similar argument for $Q_2$.  Write
$$
Q_2 = 1_{X_1X_2X_3 = 110} + \sum_{i=1}^{N-3} 1_{X_i X_{i+1} X_{i+2} X_{i+3} = 0110} + 1_{X_{N-2} X_{N-1} X_N = 011},
$$
so $\mathbb{E}[Q_2] = \frac14 + \frac{N-3}{16} \approx \frac{N}{16}$.

This argument works for any length of win streak, so you can check that in general the expected number of $k$-win streaks ($k \leq N$ obviously) is
$$
\frac{1}{2^{k}} + \frac{N-k-1}{2^{k+2}}.
$$

Comment: Thank you that seems to work, now i’m also wondering is there any way it could also be done to completely ignore losses? Like out of 1000 wins, how many of them are 1 streaks how many are 2 etc

Comment: @thing1tm The number of winning streaks of length $1$ will be about a quarter of the number of wins, and about half the number of winning streaks